# Display Transaction Hash in Frontend

Tags: transactions, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, decentralized-applications

How can we display transaction Hash in the front end using blockchain? I tried

1. `getTransactionsByAccount("*")`
2. Find transactions to/from `eth.accounts[0]` address
3. https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html

Answer (score 0):

On Console in the browser, you can use this method getTransactionReceipt(tx.result)

```
const transaction =  web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx.result);           console.log(transaction);
```

[image: output]